# How to filter the talbe using select option in php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to use the select option to update the table. these are the code and when I try it, no data have been display to table..im using js but still nothing happens..it only display the fields but no data in it. help me pls.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">150-2012-00007</option>
  <option value="2">120-2013-001</option>
  <option value="3">130-2012-0022</option>
  <option value="4">130-2012-0554</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the code for the getuser.php

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

 $db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
 $db_user = 'root'; // Username
 $db_pass = ''; // Password
 $db_name = 'ofes'; // Database Name

 $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    if (!$conn) 
        {
            die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
        }else{
            echo "";
        }
    
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE Id_number = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Id number</th>
<th>Passwordr</th>
<th>Course</th>
<th>School Year</th>
<th>Semester</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Id_number'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['course'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['school_year'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['semester'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

basically when I choose from the select option the table will be updated automatically.

Comment: First: echo $sql and print_r $result and $row and see what comes out. Also unquote $q as it is an integer.

Comment: 2nd: remove html, head and body tags from getuser.php, because you are putting this inside a div inside an existing page.

Comment: Hi, I did everything what you say but still nothing happens..

Comment: I remove the html, head and body tags, and I did the first step that you told me. but still no changes

Comment: most of the code i got it in w3 school.

Comment: here's the link https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: So ? Did those variables you printed out all contain what they were supposed to ?

Comment: ive created a table tbl_students, and it supposed to display the name, Id number and course and school year. when i try this code in w3 school, the results are fine and it filter the table.. but when i try this in my own using notepad nothing happens..no changes happened to table

Comment: i dont know what the error or problem is.

Comment: For one thing you seem to be missing the line mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo"); before $sql.

Comment: in the parameters in mysqli_select_db, is the ajax_demo is the database?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Although upon review I can't really tell why it's there, or why they changed its name from 2 lines earlier. I know for a fact I did not use mysqli_select_db in my own code.

Comment: I tried it but still no data are dispaying..only the column name

Comment: Add the line echo $sql; after your line $sql = "select etc.etc."; and add the output to the question

Comment: i got it now...tnx man :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help